# Max of an Array (SAS)

Tags: arrays, sas

I have an array of auc values, cv_auc0-cv_auc39, numbered 0-39. The maximum auc value is .7778, and it appears in several places in the array (33, 35, 38, 39). When I create the variable

```
auc_max = max(of cv_auc0-cv_auc&39);
```

It seems to identify place 39 as the maximum, even though this maximum appears elsewhere in the array.

These numbers 0-39 reflect the number of covariates in a model, and I want to keep this number as low as possible while maintaining max auc, thus I would like for the auc_max variable to identify place 33 instead of 39. How to do this?

I extract this covariate number, p, in the following code:

```
array a (*) cv_auc0-cv_auc&maxp;
  do k = &maxp to 0 by -1;
  if (a(k+1) = auc_max) then p = k;
end;


cross_val_auc = a(p+1);
keep p cross_val_auc;
```

And the p it returns is 39 instead of 33.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see anything in here that could be incorrect.  Best guess is that the max value is slightly different between the places.  If the value in place 39 is, say, 1e-6 > the value in place 33, then you will return place 39.

Here is how I would do it.  I would iterate up from the bottom and use the `leave;` statement to stop the loop.

```
data test;
array a[10] (1 2 3 4 4 3 2 4 1 4);
m = max(of a1-a10);
do p=1 to 10 ;
    if a[p] = m then leave;
end;
put m= p=;
run;
```

returns:

```
m=4 p=4
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use the `WHICHN()` function?  You might want to subtract one since your variable name suffixes start from zero instead of one.

```
auc_max = max(of cv_auc0-cv_auc&maxp);
p = whichn(auc_max,of cv_auc0-cv_auc&maxp)-1;
```